# Why does my paint brush on adobe illustrator keep doing this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, fill

My paint brush keeps changing the fill/border, It has never done this before. It makes it hard to be accurate. The eraser makes bubbled marks instead of regular smooth eraser marks. Again, Never happened before.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  What is wrong with the image you have shown? What is it supposed to look like? What are "bubbled marks"?  Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/137381/edit) to make it clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a **dashed stroke** set in the **Stroke Panel**.